# Node.js async call in event handler

Tags: node.js, events, async-await

The following code:

```
    async function eventQuery(){
    var contract_abi = await getContractAbi(CONTRACT_ADDRESS_ADDRESS_PROVIDER);
    const addressProvider = new web3Http.eth.Contract(contract_abi, CONTRACT_ADDRESS_ADDRESS_PROVIDER);
    const contract_address_1 = await addressProvider.methods.getAddress1().call();
    contract_abi = await getContractAbi(contract_address_1 );
    const contract = new web3Ws.eth.Contract(contract_abi, contract_address_1 );
    contract .events.allEvents()
    .on('data', async function(event) {
        if(event.raw.topics[0] === DEPOSIT) {
            var result = await axios.get('https://myurl.com/api/query');
            console.log(result.data);
        }
    })
    .on('error', (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }); 
}

eventQuery();
```

Sometimes I get an error
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null`

which means that the http get call is not awaited.
Has anyone an idea how to fix that?

Comment: Apparently, sometimes `await axios.get('https://myurl.com/api/query');` resolves to `null`.  You need to either test for that to avoid it or figure out why it does that sometimes.

Comment: Hi jfriend00, yes my question is, why `await axios.get()` sometimes does not resolve.

Comment: Well, you need to capture the network trace from either the server or the client when you get it resolving to `null` to see what's going on.  Nothing we can do here for you unless you provide us with a reproducible URL that will illustrate the problem.